# Accessing files in local ftp server files through terminal?

Tags: server, gnome-terminal, ftp

After connecting to a local ftp server, how can I access the files through the terminal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After establishing the connection in GNOME, you can find your FTP files mounted under ~/.gvfs

Answer (score -3):

1.- why don't you use filezilla ...

> sudo aptitude install filezilla

2.-

if you insist in download in terminal and image

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9vLjPUHjvME

3.- another option (use gnome and nautilus) :

gnome menu - place - connect to the server

public ftp  or ftp with login (with user)

tick on Add Bookmark and name of the book mark click and connect

and you can access your file via gnome menu places.